# URL Rewrite with Post

Tags: asp.net, post

I have an ASP.NET page with URL Rewrite and when I post a message to the page, it reveals the ID.  So for example, I have a page

http://www.example.com/info/earth

When I post a comment to the page, the address bar becomes

http://www.example.com/info/earth?info=earth

How do I prevent the ?info=earth from appearing in the address bar after a post submission has occurred.

My form without LT & GT is :-

form runat="server" method="post" id="fForm"

The form is on an ASP.NET control and not on the main form because I use the control on other pages rather than just the one page.  My IIS Rewrite rule is :-

```
(rule name="Rewrite for info" stopProcessing="true")
    (match url="info/(.+)" /)
    (conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll")
        (add input="{URL}" negate="true" pattern="\.axd$" /)
    (/conditions)
    (action type="Rewrite" url="info.aspx?info={R:1}" /)
(/rule)
```

Your help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Just set `appendQueryString` to `false`

```
<action type="Rewrite" url="info.aspx?info={R:1}" appendQueryString="false" />
```

Comment: Nearly there, what itused to do was if i posted many times, it'd say http://www.example.com/info/earth?info=earth&info=earth but now it only does the first info.  How do i get rid of the first?

Comment: @MiscellaneousUser I thought that parameter would do the trick, however, after further reading that just determines whether the query string from the *incoming* URL get's applied to the mapped URL. Try using [IIS Manager](http://www.iis.net/learn/extensions/url-rewrite-module/user-friendly-url-rule-template) to do the re-write.